# Can I set Bitmovin video to go fullscreen on device orientation change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, orientation, fullscreen, bitmovin-player

I am having a Bitmovin player instance and I am trying to force fullscreen when device orientation changes to landscape. Code goes like this:

```
const portrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

portrait.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    if (!e.matches && player.isPlaying() && (player.getViewMode() == 'inline')) {
        player.setViewMode('fullscreen');
    }

    if (e.matches && player.isPlaying() && (player.getViewMode() == 'fullscreen')) {
        player.setViewMode('inline');
    }
})
```

Event listener works correctly, but on Chrome in Android phones I get a `TypeError: fullscreen error`

If I force fullscreen via console in dev tools and restore to inline view, behaviour changes and video goes fullscreen on orientation change.

Researching I found that Chrome requires either user gestures for fullscreen events, or call them through an event (as is the case here) so I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Behaviour is the same using the native fullscreen api instead of bitmovin's `setViewMode()` functions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not specific to the Bitmovin Player but to the browser. I think you partly answered it yourself already:

> Researching I found that Chrome requires either user gestures for fullscreen events, or call them through an event (as is the case here) so I cannot figure out what is wrong.

User activation is required, but it seems that the `matchMedia`'s change is simply not considered such.

The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-processing-model) defines what should be considered an `activation triggering input event` as they call it:

> An activation triggering input event is any event whose `isTrusted` attribute is true and whose `type` is one of:
>
> - `keydown`, provided the key is neither the `Esc` key nor a shortcut key reserved by the user agent.
> - `mousedown`.
> - `pointerdown`, provided the event's `pointerType` is "mouse".
> - `pointerup`, provided the event's `pointerType` is not "mouse".
> - `touchend`.

As you see, the event you try to use is not in this list.
If those are truly the only events considered by Chrome, then I don't think your desired behavior is feasible.